# Как создать кнопку в телеграмм для оплаты telebot на python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

помогите пожалуйста, сижу 2 день уже каша в голове. Необходимо реализовать оплату по кнопке (ИП есть, выбрал платежную систему ЮКасса), на библиотеке telebot (мне она легче дается, чем aiogram), но все примеры которые есть на просторах только на aiograg, нашел единственный пример только на гитхабе и то он не рабочий заброшен.
То есть я хочу, что бы по одной из множества кнопок человек нажимал в зависимости от нужного ему товара и как при стандартной оплате в телеге вылезало окно, соответственно если платеж прошел/не прошел об этом писалось. Я вижу что это реализовано у многих, но сам не могу понять за что зацепится. Пока все что есть это такой черновик. В моем случае человек предположим нажимает в первом меню на 4 и появляется группа товаров 1 2 3, при нажатии на одной из этих цифр(товар со своей суммой) соответственно вылетает окно с оплатой и т.д. Если кто то поможет мне, хоть чем то, буду очень благодарен.

```
 import telebot
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types


from telebot import types



bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
PAYMENTS_TOKEN = "TOKEN"
PRICE = types.LabeledPrice(label="Оплата", amount=40000*100) #в копейках



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(massage):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('1', url='https://habr.com/ru/')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('2', url='https://habr.com/ru/')
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3', url='https://habr.com/ru/')
    item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='ok1')
    markup.add(item, item2, item3, item4)
    
    bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, 'прочитай инструкцию для своего товара', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'ok1':
            markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Товар 1', callback_data='tovar')
            item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Товар 2', callback_data='tovar 2')
            item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Товар 3', callback_data='tovar 3')
            markup2.add(item5, item6, item7)

            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'выберите тавар', reply_markup=markup2)



bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```